# How to merge multiple child entities of a parent entity

Tags: swift, core-data

I had a parent entity with 2 child entity in Core Data.
I saved one of the child entity which includes attributes of parent's. How can I add the other child entity by appending data into previous instead of generate an empty one with only the second child's attribute?

Core data:
[image]

Code:

```
@Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var moc

@FetchRequest(entity: Parent.entity(), sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Parent.parentName, ascending: true)]) var parent: FetchedResults<Parent>
@FetchRequest(entity: Son.entity(), sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Son.boysName, ascending: true)]) var son: FetchedResults<Son>
@FetchRequest(entity: Daughter.entity(), sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Daughter.girlsName, ascending: true)]) var daughter: FetchedResults<Daughter>

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Button(action: {
            let theSon = Son(context: moc)
            let theDaughter = Daughter(context: moc)
            theSon.boysName = "Big brother"
            theSon.parentName = "Father"
            theDaughter.girlsName = "Baby sister"
            theDaughter.parentName = "Father"
            PersistenceController.shared.save(info: "saved")
        }, label: {
            Text("add family list")
        })
    }
}
```

SQLlite:
I can save each of child, but they are in different rows as following picture.
How can I merge them into the same one?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ThT84.png)

I had tried to insert into Son entity but it failed:

```
let theDaughter = Daughter(entity: Son.entity(), insertInto: moc)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wsQSQ.png)

Comment: Your design is not correct, you are using inheritance so you are saying that a Son _is a_ Father and a Daughter _is a_ Father which is probably not what you meant (and you are limited to have max two children for each Father). You should have one entity Parent and one Child with a to-many relationship between them

Comment: Thank you for your advice, knowing that i can take one-to-many relationship to unlimited the children's count, my purpose is to know how to merge child entities, but I designed an unsuitable example. ^_^